# Statistics module not effect with Services module

Tags: services, nodes

I created a Services Views, I added a **Statistics field**(total view) to the Views.

Then I try to use the browser to visit the node through RESTful api, like this url: `http://daxuebao.local:8083/api/node/61`

But, when I try to visit the Service Views, the Statistics field not effect, It still zero.

How to make Services support Statistics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statistics increments hits in [`hook_exit`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_exit/7) i.e:

[`statistics_exit`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!statistics!statistics.module/function/statistics_exit/7)

It's normally called as part of [`drupal_exit`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_exit/7) in [`drupal_page_footer`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_page_footer/7)

In any case, `statistics_exit` for the node counter actually checks

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && arg(2) == NULL) {}
```

That won't be true on an api request URL.

You might need to implement

[`hook_services_request_postprocess_alter`](http://drupalcode.org/project/services.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/docs/services.alter.api.php)

check the node request and make the stats increment call yourself.

Something like:

```
/**
 * Alter results of the services call.
 *
 * @param $controller
 *   Controller definition
 * @param array $args
 *   Arguments passed to services callback
 * @param array $result
 *   Array of results that can be altered
 *
 * @see services_controller_execute()
 * @see services.runtime.inc
 */
function MODULE_services_request_postprocess_alter($controller, $args, &$result) {
  // Increment hit count for node view api requests.
  $nid = $result->nid; // May need to confirm this is the node id.
  if($controller['callback'] == '_node_resource_retrieve'){
    // See statistics_exit()
    if (variable_get('statistics_count_content_views', 0)) {
      // A node has been requested, so update the node's counters.
      db_merge('node_counter')->key(array('nid' => $nid))->fields(array(
        'daycount' => 1,
        'totalcount' => 1,
        'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
      ))->expression('daycount', 'daycount + 1')->expression('totalcount', 'totalcount + 1')->execute();
    }
  }
}
```